# Store images on server as files or in database as byte array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm developing a website which allows the user to upload an image per item (I guess there will be hundreds per user).

What is more preferred:

1. to save the images as bytes in the DB (mongodb) or
2. as files in the server?

I don't really know where to place this question in the "Stack Exchange" forums.

Thanks (even for directing me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb has a document size restriction (16MB) per document.

What you could consider is use GridFS for storing images as this can be sharded, so load can be splited to different servers.

[See gridFS manual for more information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed
>   the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.
>
> Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the
>   file into parts, or chunks [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), and stores each chunk as a separate
>   document. By default, GridFS uses a chunk size of 255 kB; that is,
>   GridFS divides a file into chunks of 255 kB with the exception of the
>   last chunk. The last chunk is only as large as necessary. Similarly,
>   files that are no larger than the chunk size only have a final chunk,
>   using only as much space as needed plus some additional metadata.

Comment: Thanks, the information helped me to decided - I`ll save it as a files.